# ag-Gird:setting tabindex to Columns

Tags: html, angular, ag-grid

Is it possible to change the tabindexs according to the change of columns order??

I am using FloatingFilter of ag-Grid.When the order of columns was changed, tabindex won't follow, but still remain the initial order.

Answer (score 1):

Taking control of you navigation by providing your own tabToNextCell function should do the trick:

> **tabToNextCell**
>
> Provide a callback tabToNextCell if you want to override the tab key
>   navigation.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-keyboard-navigation/#gsc.tab=0

Comment: Thank you. I read the page before and thought it worked to only cells. Does it work to floating filters too??